# Memory is not being freed automatically in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I am currently working in windows phone 8. I am facing some memory related problems.

Let I have two PhoneApplicationPages. Both pages contain images, text-blocks etc. Suppose when I am in page-1 my app is using 30MB of memory. If I navigate from page-1 to page-2 the amount of used memory increased to 35MB. Then when I go back to page-1, the used memory is still 35MB.

Why memory or cache is not being freed automatically? Is there any way to clear memory or cache manually?

(p.s: both of the classes that are representing the pages are static and I am setting them to null in **OnNavigatedFrom** method.)

Answer (score 4):

For some reasons I'm unaware of, the runtime keeps a reference to your page for a while, even after the page has been removed from the back stack. I've documented my findings on this behavior here: http://blogs.codes-sources.com/kookiz/archive/2013/11/11/wpdev-give-that-memory-back.aspx

Long story short, add this code to your pages if you want to reclaim the memory immediately:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

    this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
    {
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

            this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
            {
                GC.Collect();
                GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Note that it's not really a leak, even if you don't use this code your memory will eventually get released (typically after about three page navigations). But freeing the memory earlier can really help for memory-intensive applications.

Answer (score 3):

From this [link](http://www.csharphelp.com/2006/08/garbage-collection/):

> The garbage collector (GC) of .NET completely absolves the developer
>   from tracking memory usage and knowing when to free memory.
>
> The Microsoft? .NET CLR (Common Language Runti me) requires that all
>   resources be allocated from the managed heap. You never free objects
>   from the managed heap-objects are automatically freed when they are no
>   longer needed by the application.
>
> Memory is not infinite. The garbage collector must perform a
>   collection in order to free some memory. The garbage collector’s
>   optimizing engine determines the best time to perform a collection,
>   (the exact criteria is guarded by Microsoft) based upon the
>   allocations being made.

Basically, the Garbage collector frees memory form the system, but it is not active all the time as it would be performance consuming.

You can force the GC to do the collection by calling the `GC.Collect();` method, as explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xe0c2357(v=vs.110).aspx).

Now, forcing the Garbage collector to execute is not a good idea, but you can help it by using a [class destructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66x5fx1b.aspx):

```
class YourClass
{
    ~YourClass()  // destructor
    {
        // cleanup statements.
    }
}
```

Comment: How would destructor help?